# ace:checkboxButton inside ace:tree. Event Listener is not invoked

Tags: jsf-2, icefaces

Hello I am new to JSF ice faces, and i am stuck on one point.

I have checkboxButton inside a tree. The checkboxes has associated action listeners. 
Issue is that the action listener is only invoked for the top level check box (at the root node), not for the checkbox which are at the child or leaf of the tree. Am i missing something?

```
<ace:tree var="treeNode" value="#{clientUserAdmin.segmentationTree}" expansion="true"  selection="false"  reordering="false"
                                rendered="#{!empty clientUserAdmin.clientAccessSelectList and !clientUserAdmin.currentProfile.allSegmentations and user.currentProject.isSegmentationManual}" >
                                <ace:node>
                                        <h:panelGroup style="display: inline">
                                        <ace:checkboxButton partialSubmit="true"
                                            value="#{treeNode.userObject.treeNodeSelected}"
                                            valueChangeListener="#{clientUserAdmin.onSegmentationAccessChange}"
                                            styleClass="#{treeNode.userObject.classStyle}"
                                            disabled="#{treeNode.userObject.checkBoxDisabled}" >
                                            <ace:ajax execute="@this" render="@all" />
                                            </ace:checkboxButton>
                                        </h:panelGroup>

                                        <h:panelGroup style="display: inline">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{treeNode.userObject.text}"
                                                styleClass="#{treeNode.userObject.classStyle}" />
                                        </h:panelGroup>
                                </ace:node>
                            </ace:tree>
```

I can see that the request is sent to the server and onSuccess is always executed for every check box value change. but value change listener is never invoked for child node check boxes.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the solution to the original issue.

I changed to my code to use h:selectBooleanCheckbox   instead of ace:checkboxButton

Also instead of ace:ajax execute="@this" render="@all", i changed to 
f:ajax event="click" execute="@form" render="@form"

Now it is working as expected. If someone can explain what is happening, will be a great help.

thanks.